# docker caddy proxy not forwarding

Tags: docker-compose, caddy, caddyfile

So I set up the caddy server using docker and have set it to proxy to another docker image that is running nodejs. However, when i hit the url it is routing to caddyserver.com instead of my nodejs. Is there something that I am missing:

```
myserver {
  proxy / 172.17.0.5:8000 {
    header_upstream Host {host}
    header_upstream X-Real-IP {remote}
    header_upstream X-Forwarded-For {remote}
    header_upstream X-Forwarded-Proto {scheme}
  }
}
```

My docker-compose looks like following:

```
web:
 image: ca9a385372b0
 env_file: .env
 environment:
 AUTO_ALIASES: /src/docker/aliases/auto
 TERM: xterm-256color
 VIRTUAL_HOST: myserver
 VIRTUAL_PORT: 8000
 volumes:
  - .:/src
ports:
 - "8000:8000"
container_name: web
links:
  - caddy
caddy:
  image: blackglory/caddy-proxy:0.2.1
  env_file: .env
  environment:
  CADDY_OPTIONS: "-email someaddress@myserver.com"
  volumes:
   - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
  ports:
   - "80:80"
  - "443:443"
```

i added following to my /etc/hosts also

```
127.0.0.1 myserver
```

However, when I goto http://myserver it redirects me to caddyserver.com

my .env file looks like this

```
 WEB_VIRTUAL_HOST=myserver
 WEB_VIRTUAL_PORT=8000
```

Comment: Where/how are you making your Caddyfile available to Caddy?

Comment: Ah, I guess it generates one automatically. It looks like you might be missing a volume. The caddy-proxy README also has `-v /data/.caddy:/root/.caddy`.

Comment: I guess, I was expecting caddy to pick it up from /etc/Caddyfile where the file was created by the caddy docker image. however, I did add VOLUME   `${HOME}/.caddy:/root/.caddy` but it didnt work

Comment: caddy will find the Caddyfile in the directory that contains the caddy binary -  otherwise you can specify another location by using -conf=path/to/Caddyfile

Comment: The caddy file is set correctly i assume. When I goto localhost it also redirects me to caddyserver website which seems weird.